# Karate Gatling : ERROR io.gatling.app.Gatling$ - Run crashed , DataWriters didn't initialize properly

Tags: gradle, karate

I am working on running Karate tests as Gatling performance tests. The framework and integration worked fine using Maven. However, we need to use Gradle for our project. After integrating with gradle, **./gradlew gatlingRun --debug** is failing with below error.I also tried with root user and got the same output. I am suspecting it might be related to configuration issue with how gatling.conf is used to initialize  LogFileDataWriter. Has anyone faced this issue and know how to fix this? Please find below the build.gradle and scala class for reference.

Exception:

```
2021-02-17T01:45:18.752-0800 [QUIET] [system.out] 01:45:18.751 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] ERROR i.g.c.stats.writer.LogFileDataWriter - DataWriter failed to initialize
2021-02-17T01:45:18.752-0800 [QUIET] [system.out] java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /pay-integration-tests: Read-only file system
2021-02-17T01:45:18.752-0800 [QUIET] [system.out]       at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:100)
.
.
.
2021-02-17T01:45:18.757-0800 [QUIET] [system.out] 01:45:18.752 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] INFO  i.g.c.stats.writer.ConsoleDataWriter - Initialized
2021-02-17T01:45:18.757-0800 [QUIET] [system.out] 01:45:18.757 [main] ERROR io.gatling.app.Gatling$ - Run crashed
2021-02-17T01:45:18.757-0800 [QUIET] [system.out] java.lang.Exception: DataWriters didn't initialize properly
2021-02-17T01:45:18.757-0800 [QUIET] [system.out]       at io.gatling.core.stats.DataWritersStatsEngine$.$anonfun$apply$6(StatsEngine.scala:99)
```

```html
plugins {
    id "idea"
        id "eclipse"
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'scala'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.21'
}
ext {
    karateVersion = '0.9.6'
    scalalibraryVersion = '2.12.10'
}

group = 'com.expedia.payments'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }

    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2')
    testRuntime('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.2')

    testImplementation "com.intuit.karate:karate-junit5:${karateVersion}"
    testImplementation "com.intuit.karate:karate-apache:${karateVersion}"
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:${scalalibraryVersion}"
    testCompile "com.intuit.karate:karate-gatling:${karateVersion}"

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.11'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.23'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: '5.3.3'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc
    compile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '9.2.0.jre11'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds
    implementation group: 'net.sourceforge.jtds', name: 'jtds', version: '1.3.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc42
    //implementation group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'sqljdbc42', version: '6.0.8112'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperty "karate.options", System.properties.getProperty("karate.options")
    systemProperty "karate.env", System.properties.getProperty("karate.env")
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}

sourceSets {
    test {
        resources {
            srcDir file('src/test/java')
            scala {
                srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
            }
            exclude '**/*.java'
            exclude '**/*.scala'
        }

    }
}

// to run, type: "gradle gatling"
task gatlingRun(type: JavaExec) {
    group = 'Web Tests'
    description = 'Run Gatling Tests'
    new File("/pay-integration-tests/reports/gatling").mkdirs()
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    main = "io.gatling.app.Gatling"
    args = [
            // change this to suit your simulation entry-point
            '-s', 'performanceTestSimulation',
            '-rf', "/pay-integration-tests/reports/gatling"
    ]
    systemProperties System.properties
}
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

```js
import java.util.Calendar

import ch.qos.logback.classic.{Level, LoggerContext}
import com.intuit.karate.gatling.PreDef._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

import scala.concurrent.duration._

class performanceTestSimulation extends Simulation {

  def datetimeStamp= Calendar.getInstance.getTime

  val context: LoggerContext = LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory.asInstanceOf[LoggerContext]
  // Set Log Level to Error during Perf Test execution
  context.getLogger("io.gatling.http").setLevel(Level.valueOf("ERROR"))

  /** To Use karate-name passed in header as Request Name in Gatling report - Start**/

  val protocol = karateProtocol(
  )
  protocol.nameResolver = (req, ctx) => req.getHeader("karate-name")

  /** To Use karate-name passed in header as Request Name in Gatling report - End **/


  //  val perftest1 = scenario("Perf Test Dispute API Workflow - Single Feature File").exec(karateFeature("classpath:examples/MARS/DisputeAPI.feature")).exec(session => {
  //    println("*** Session status in Gatling: " + session.status)
  //    session
  //  })

  val perftest1 = scenario("Perf Test Credit Card Successful Refund").exec(karateFeature("classpath:com/payments/integrationtests/creditcard/creditCardSuccessfulFullRefund.feature")).exec(session => {
    println(datetimeStamp + "   Session status in Gatling: " + session.status)
    session
  })

  val perftest2 = scenario("Perf Test PayPal").exec(karateFeature("classpath:com/payments/integrationtests/pxecosystem/travel.feature")).exec(session => {
    println(datetimeStamp + "   Session status in Gatling: " + session.status)
    session
  })

  //Mixed Perf Test Scenario

  //Closed  Workload

  setUp(

    perftest1.inject(
      incrementConcurrentUsers(50) // Int
        .times(5)
        .eachLevelLasting(5.minutes)
        .separatedByRampsLasting(10.seconds)
        .startingFrom(10) // Int
    ).protocols(protocol),

    //Open Workload

    perftest2.inject(
      incrementUsersPerSec(5) // Double
        .times(5)
        .eachLevelLasting(10.seconds)
        .separatedByRampsLasting(10.seconds)
        .startingFrom(10)// Double

    ).protocols(protocol),

    //Throttling scenario

    //    perftest1.inject(constantUsersPerSec(5).during(5.minutes))).throttle(
    //      reachRps(25).in(10.seconds),
    //      holdFor(1.minute),
    //      jumpToRps(50),
    //      holdFor(5.minutes)
    //    ).protocols(protocol)

  ).maxDuration(5.minutes).assertions(forAll.responseTime.mean.lt(2000),
    forAll.responseTime.percentile(99).lt(5000),
    forAll.failedRequests.percent.lt(0.01))


}
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed. The problem was with the path where the gatling report will be written . It should be -rf', "pay-integration-tests/reports/gatling" and not -rf', "/pay-integration-tests/reports/gatling". The / refers to root directory.

[java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Read-only file system) Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59658422/java-io-filenotfoundexception-read-only-file-system-mac)